How to edit html from a already existing document.createElement('element')?
I need to edit a already existing element how do I do this?
function name(item) {
  var newItem = document.createElement('div')
  newItem.innerHTML = item
  //if num1 > 1 then edit innerHTML of Item to be 2 else append newItem to div
}


<div class="overlayTxt">`

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

You probably want the appendChild method. This will push the element into the bottom of the list.
In this example I'm using document.body which is the root dom node. If you want something more specific you'll need to select the element you want to append to with querySelector


function name(item) {
  var newItem = document.createElement('div')
  newItem.innerHTML = item
  document.body.appendChild(newItem)
  //if num1 > 1 then edit innerHTML of Item to be 2 else append newItem to div
}
name('abc')



